# Making text into an array - Swift

Tags: swift, csv

For fun I'm helping my school out by creating an app which has all class cancellations for student use. From my IT technician I got a quite complex structure containing class name, teacher, and other information looking like this:

```
 3818,"20170217",5,752,64,"Rh",,"fr_2",,,,"iV5",,,"IS10a~IS10b~IS10c~IS10d","Z",,1,"IS10a~IS10b~IS10c~IS10d",C,201702161517,"-"

 3819,"20170217",6,752,102,"Rh",,"fr",,,,"iB3","iB3",,"IT10a","Z",,0,"IT10a",,201702161517,"-"

 3820,"20170217",8,752,119,"Rh",,"fr",,,,"iC1.2","iC1.2",,"IS6a","Z",,0,"IS6a",,201702161517,"-"

 3821,"20170227",2,753,207,"Dd","Kru","sc",,,,"iB8","iB8",,"IS9b","Z",,2097152,"IS9b",,201702270804,"+~-"

 3822,"20170227",3,753,8,"Dd",,"phH_1",,,,"iB8",,,"IS12~IT12","Z",,2097153,"IS12~IT12",C,201702270804,"-"

 3823,"20170227",4,753,29,"Dd",,"phH_1",,,,"iB8",,,"IS11~IT11","Z",,2097153,"IS11~IT11",C,201702270804,"-"

 3824,"20170227",5,753,30,"Dd",,"phH_1",,,,"iB8",,,"IS11~IT11","Z",,2097153,"IS11~IT11",C,201702270804,"-"

 3825,"20170227",6,753,7,"Dd",,"phH_1",,,,"iB8",,,"IS12~IT12","Z",,2097153,"IS12~IT12",C,201702270804,"-"

 3826,"20170227",7,753,327,"Dd",,"COV",,,,"AC1",,,,"Z",,2097153,,,201702270803,

 3827,"20170227",8,753,46,"Dd",,"ph_1",,,,"iB8",,,"IS10a~IS10b~IS10c~IS10d~IT10a~IT10b","Z",,2097153,"IS10a~IS10b~IS10c~IS10d~IT10a~IT10b",C,201702270804,"-"
```

From this data I need to get various pieces, such as "20170217" and put them into an array for later use. How would I best do this? For anyone who cares, I added the full snippet below!

https://jsfiddle.net/pztwfsq1/

Comment: Hi Sven, Stackoverflow is a great place to go to when you have tried a few things first. If you have tried and still failing, document what you have tried. SO community will probably NOT answer this question as it stands.

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice, I'm kind of new here. I'm going to inspect CSV then. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is one dataset per line you can iterate through all lines. Split each line at `,` and you'll have an array of the information.

Similar to this (to give you an idea):

```
let row = "1,Peter,5,92,,Brooklyn"
let data = row.components(separatedBy: ",")

let name = data[1] // Peter
let location = data[5] // Brooklyn
```